# How to get TeamCity to ignore NUnit test case in debug?

Tags: nunit, teamcity

Test case that were failing in debug was set to be ignored in debug. TeamCity still runs the test on the build machine.

The test is ignored in debug on my local machine.

Some other tests that are ignored for both release and debug configurations are ignored on the build machine.

I have checked that TeamCity builds in debug, I have set Command line parameters to "/p:Configuration=Debug".

I have checked the the build step for debug tests runs from the bin\Debug folder.

This is the configuration for this build step: 
[image]

I have several build configurations on TeamCity and the other configurations ignore tests when I use compiler directives like in the example below.

```
    [Test]
    [Category("IntegrationTestLongRunning")]
    [Category("Algorithm")]
    #if DEBUG
     [Ignore("Too slow in debug.")]
    #endif
    public void UnitTest()
    {
        // Some test code...
    }
```

I expect the test with Ignore within compiler directives not be run in debug configuration on the build server.

Comment: How does you build configuration look like? Could you add print screen to your question?

Comment: @Peska, screenshot added.